# CSS styles behave differently inside & outside iframe

Tags: css, iframe, html-lists

Nested list looks differently in normal html and inside iframe.  Take a look at first li: inside iframe ol element does not wrap to next line if li has no text.

Here is the fiddle:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/Lwj9jjj1/1/`
```

I assume it has to do something with html5. Iframe probably does not act according to html standard behavior.

I had the same issue with images - inside iframe they did not have vertical space after them, while not in iframe - they had. I fixed that by adding vertical-align property to image. The fiddle:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/Lwj9jjj1`
```

Comment: Next time, please don't use tricks like that to avoid posting code in your question. There is no good reason to not post code.

Comment: Believe it or not but I could not find a way how to embed jsfiddle link to a question. I was getting an error that I needed to wrap it in code by 4 space or smth like that, but not very clear to me. I tried various ways and only this worked.

Comment: That's not what the error message says. It says you need to post _code_ in the message. That is, the HTML and/or JavaScript that you have problems with. Not only a link to an external website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using quirks mode in the iframe, so yes, your iframe behaves differently from the main fiddle, which uses standards mode.

Solution: use standards mode in the iframe as well.

```js
var content = '<!DOCTYPE html><title></title> <ol> <li> <ol> <li>a</li><li> <ol> <li>b</li></ol> </li></ol> </li></ol>';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwj9jjj1/3/